# Is it possible to have 2 different classes in a SparseArray?

Tags: android

I am currently using a `SparseArray` and want to have data from 2 different classes in them, is this a possibility?

Comment: I assume you mean `SparseArray` ? Yes, it is possible. Please show the problem you are having otherwise with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make like this.

```
interface FruitInterface { /* common methods */ } 
public class Apple implements FruitInterface { } 
public class Pear implements FruitInterface { }

SparseArray<FruitInterface> fruits = new SparseArray<FruitInterface>();
```

Or you can make like this.

```
SparseArray<Object> fruits = new SparseArray<Object>();
```

and then check

```
if (fruits.get(0) instanceof Apple) {
} else if (fruits.get(0) instanceof Pear) {
}
```